# How get conditional nested relationship of parent polymorphic relationship in laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel

```
$share2 = Share::with(['Post' => function($query){
    $query->with(['Postable']);
}])
    ->whereHas('Post',function ($query){
        $query->when('postable_type' == App\Models\User,function ($query){
            $query->whereHas('Postable',function ($query){
                $query->whereHas('Follower',function ($query){
                    $query->where('user_id', auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->id : null);
                });
            });
        })->when('postable_type' == App\Models\Agency ,function ($query){
            $query->whereHas('Friend', function ($query) {
                $query->where('mirror_user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                $query->where('status', 'friend');
            });
        });
// I have used when but it seems useless for my case
        })
        ->where('shareable_type', 'App\Models\User')
        ->where('shareable_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->orWhere('shareable_type', 'App\Models\Agency')
        ->orWhere('shareable_id', 1)
        ->get();
```

I have a polymorphic relationship (`Postable`) on `Post` model, `Postable` return either `Agency` model or `User` model, then from `Postable` I want get `Follower` if the `Postable` was `App\Models\Agency`, or get `Friend` if the `Postable` was `App\Models\User`, my `User` has not `Follower` relationship because it is for `Agency` model, instead `User` has `Friend` relationship that `Agency` has not. now I want to check if the `Postable` was `App\Models\Agency` then return `Follower` relationship if it was `User` then return `Friend`.

relationships structure:

Share -> Post -> Postable(Agency,User)

Agency->Follower

User->Friend

hope I my explanation will take place in your mind

thanks in advance

Comment: i belive you can do it yourself with this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-morph-to-relationships

Comment: Thanks for the thread, just for remineder the ($type) variable is very usful for this case